# Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME freeze with general protection fault in ttm_page_pool_get_pages

Tags: 18.04, gnome, segmentation-fault

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 on a MacBookPro11,5 with the default GNOME desktop, and I keep getting  freezes where nothing works except moving the mouse pointer, there is no response to alt+F2, Ctrl+Alt+F2, or Ctrl+Alt+F3, and I have to hard-reboot.  The culprit is consistent, as far as I can deduce from /var/log/syslog: it's a function called ttm_page_pool_get_pages that ultimately crashes at entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe.  That sounds like pretty low-level memory management stuff which is way beyond my Linux expertise.  Here is a typical case (I have not diffed to see if it is always the exact same sequence of messages, but it always *looks* the same by eye):

```
Mar 29 10:05:01 McBk CRON[1276]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405460] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405464] CPU: 0 PID: 2151 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G           OE     5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405465] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro11,5/Mac-06F11F11946D27C5, BIOS MBP114.88Z.0184.B00.1806051659 06/05/2018
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405470] RIP: 0010:clear_page_erms+0x7/0x10
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405472] Code: 48 89 47 18 48 89 47 20 48 89 47 28 48 89 47 30 48 89 47 38 48 8d 7f 40 75 d9 90 c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 b9 00 10 00 00 31 c0 <f3> aa c3 90 90 90 90 90 90 55 48 85 ff 48 89 e5 0f 84 fd 00 00 00
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405473] RSP: 0018:ffffa992c36537f8 EFLAGS: 00010246
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405474] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9a6e23b1d090 RCX: 0000000000001000
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405475] RDX: ffff9a6c7929c350 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: ffed64780a70d000
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405476] RBP: ffffa992c3653868 R08: 0000000000000201 R09: ffff9a6e23b1d098
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405476] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff9a6e23b1d090 R12: 0000000000000000
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405477] R13: 0000000000000040 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffa992c36538a8
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405478] FS:  00007f8558727a80(0000) GS:ffff9a6e2f000000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405479] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405480] CR2: 00007f8509e7f1c0 CR3: 000000040c614003 CR4: 00000000001606f0
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405481] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405481] DR3: 0000000000000080 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000020000400
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405482] Call Trace:
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405489]  ? ttm_page_pool_get_pages+0x1ff/0x380 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405492]  ? si_mem_available+0x5b/0xe0
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405495]  ttm_pool_populate+0xfd/0x4a0 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405497]  ttm_populate_and_map_pages+0x28/0x260 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405513]  radeon_ttm_tt_populate+0x87/0x150 [radeon]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405515]  ttm_tt_populate.part.9+0x22/0x60 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405517]  ttm_tt_bind+0x51/0x60 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405520]  ttm_bo_handle_move_mem+0x4f2/0x5b0 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405522]  ? ttm_bo_mem_space+0x17e/0x2f0 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405525]  ttm_bo_validate+0x122/0x140 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405536]  ? drm_mode_set_crtcinfo+0x56/0x1b0 [drm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405539]  ttm_bo_init_reserved+0x3a4/0x440 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405541]  ttm_bo_init+0x6b/0x110 [ttm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405551]  ? radeon_update_memory_usage.isra.7+0x50/0x50 [radeon]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405560]  radeon_bo_create+0x16e/0x200 [radeon]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405569]  ? radeon_update_memory_usage.isra.7+0x50/0x50 [radeon]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405579]  radeon_gem_object_create+0xb0/0x190 [radeon]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405590]  radeon_gem_create_ioctl+0x6b/0x100 [radeon]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405596]  ? drm_gem_handle_delete+0x74/0x90 [drm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405606]  ? radeon_gem_pwrite_ioctl+0x30/0x30 [radeon]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405612]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xb0/0x100 [drm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405618]  drm_ioctl+0x389/0x450 [drm]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405628]  ? radeon_gem_pwrite_ioctl+0x30/0x30 [radeon]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405631]  ? unmap_region+0xf7/0x130
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405637]  radeon_drm_ioctl+0x4f/0x80 [radeon]
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405640]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa9/0x640
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405642]  ksys_ioctl+0x75/0x80
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405643]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405646]  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x130
Mar 29 10:05:32 McBk kernel: [69240.405647]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
```

## Does anyone know how to fix/prevent this?

Added later in response to the suggestion:
What we really would like to see is the results of these queries immediately before a freeze, but since there's no way to get those data, I guess this will have to do!  I'm a little more conscientious about not keeping many files open per app, or many apps running at the same time, and I haven't had another freeze since I started doing that, so this probably under-represents the use of system resources I was using at the time, but not radically:

`dgibson@McBk:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        5.4G        6.2G        682M        3.9G        9.1G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
dgibson@McBk:~$ sudo lshw -C memory
[sudo] password for dgibson: 
  *-cache:0

       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 0
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 1
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:2
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 2
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:3
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 3
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-cache:4
       description: L4 cache
       physical id: 4
       slot: Unknown
       size: 128MiB
       capacity: 128MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=4
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Apple Inc.
       physical id: 6
       version: MBP114.88Z.0184.B00.1806051659
       date: 06/05/2018
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect acpi smartbattery netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: HMT41GS6BFR8A-PB
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 0
          serial: 0x00000000
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: HMT41GS6BFR8A-PB
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 1
          serial: 0x00000000
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
dgibson@McBk:~$` 

I ran the free memory test from [memtest86.com](https://memtest86.com), and it passed the entire battery of tests with zero errors.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete. Report back.

Comment: Thank you, heynnema!  More after the memtest...